# How can we use 'extended' true or false both in one project

Tags: node.js, body-parser, express-4

I am working on nodejs with express and in my project I require the filter as well as nested object.

If I set this middleware for bodyparser

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json('application/json'));
```

then filter is working properly but nested object gives undefined value

[image]

look at that in picture I search amit and i get only one record which name is amit

if I set this middleware for bodyparser

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json('application/json'));
```

then nested object works properly but filter gives undefined value

[image]

I search amit and I get all records.

how can I get both of value properly?

Please help

Comment: can you provide example for which filter is not working properly when `extended: true` ?

Comment: look at this example brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make extended false you can't pass nested objects. The middleware is used for extracting body contents from the incoming requests. So you can do one thing,
use the following code

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json('application/json'));
```

and extract object using dot(.) operator instead of req.body['....[...]']

for example,

```
req.body.search.value
```

works fine, but

```
req.body['search[value]']
```

may be undefined